# Efficient way to read a lot of text files using python

Tags: python, file

I have about 20000 documents in subdirectories. And I would like to read them all and append them as a one list of lists. This is my code so far,

```
topics =os.listdir(my_directory)
df =[]
for topic in topics:
    files = os.listdir (my_directory+ '/'+ topic)
    print(files)

    for file in files: 
        print(file)
        f = open(my_directory+ '/'+ topic+ '/'+file, 'r', encoding ='latin1')
        data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ')
        print(data)
        f.close()
    df = np.append(df, data)
```

However this is inefficient, and it takes a long time to read and append them in the df list. My expected output is,

```
 df= [[doc1], [doc2], [doc3], [doc4],......,[doc20000]]
```

I ran the above code and it took more than 6 hours and was still not finished(probably did half of the documents).How can I change the code to make it faster?

Comment: I notice that you've flagged this as 'machine learning', and as such I won't answer your question exactly but give a couple suggestions. It's generally bad practice to load all of your data simultaneously into memory, especially since you can perform reads while you're doing your other calculations. You should use the multiprocessing module to take advantage of another core to go and collect the next N batches while you're model is computing gradients (or whatever it does). Otherwise, your code looks fine (could be improved with context managers), but needs to be multi-threaded.

Comment: As an aside, since `df = np.append(df, data)` is outside of the loop, you are throwing all but the last `data` away.

Comment: Opening 20 000 text files takes a lot of time in itself. Perhaps you could write a seperate code to convert those to something like 100 csv files which are a lot faster to read?

Comment: Remove the `print(data)` call in the loop. Printing stuff takes a surprisingly long time what with all the scrolling, and it can be even slower if you're running the script in an IDE or something other than the terminal.

Comment: How big are these files and do you have enough RAM to hold them? It shouldn't take hours to read enough data to swamp your RAM. At some point you may start thrashing the swap file, but eventually it'll all blow up.

Comment: I have 16GB ram, Each file is about 4KB-10 KB, they contains emails.

Comment: Oh, and @kindall has the best suggestion of them all.

Comment: That's only a couple of hundred megs.... the file reads should be done in the minute range, not hours. This is a local hard drive?

Comment: Yes, I a using my own PC, and all the data in local hard drive.

Comment: I'm not sure how much copying is done in `df = np.append(df, data)`. You may be better off with a regular python list and creating the np array once at the end when you know the size.

Answer (score 1):

There is only so much you can do to speed disk access. You can use threads to overlap some file read operations with the `latin1` decode and newline replacement. But realistically, it won't make a huge difference.

```
import multiprocessing.pool

MEG = 2**20
filelist = []

topics =os.listdir(my_directory)
for topic in topics:
    files = os.listdir (my_directory+ '/'+ topic)
    print(files)

    for file in files: 
        print(file)
        filelist.append(my_directory+ '/'+ topic+ '/'+file)

def worker(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding ='latin1',  bufsize=1*MEG) as f:
        data = f.read().replace('\n', ' ')
        #print(data)
        return data

with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
    datalist = pool.map(worker, filelist, chunksize=1)
df = np.array(datalist)
```

Comment: can it be done using MPI too ? Can you suggest a solution based on MPI?

Comment: Sure, but I think MPI would be slower because you'd have to copy data between processes. This task is likely I/O bound and just letting one thread wait on reads while another is converting is about the best you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

> Generator functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like
>   an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.

[generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

[lazy function generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
def read_in_chunks(file, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


with open('big_file.dat') as f:
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
        process_data(piece)

class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
    def read(self, n=0):
        try:
            return next(self.g)
        except StopIteration:
            return ''

df = pd.concat(list(pd.read_csv(Reader(read_in_chunks()),chunksize=10000)),axis=1)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This is not a big file. This dataset contains 20000 folders in subdirectories. My aim is to read them one by one and append them in a list of lists.

Comment: Ok, there is a Reader() which put data in datframe and write in csv.

Answer (score 0):

## Note

I misread the line `df = np.append(df, data)` and I assumed you are appending to DataFrame, not to numpy array. So my comment is kind of irrelevant but I am leaving it for others that my misread like me or have a similar problem with pandas' DataFrame append.

---

## Actual Problem

It looks like your question may not actually solve your actual problem.
Have you measured the performance of your two most important calls?

- `files = os.listdir (my_directory+ '/'+ topic)`
- `df = np.append(df, data)`

The way you formatted your code makes me think there is a bug: `df = np.append(df, data)` is outside the file's for loop scope so I think only your last `data` is appended to your data frame. In case that's just problem with code formatting here in the post and you really do append 20k files to your data frame then this may be the problem - appending to `DataFrame` is slow.

## Potential Solution

As usual slow performance can be tackled by throwing more memory at the problem. If you have enough memory to load `all` of the files beforehand and only then insert them in a DataFrame this could prove to be faster.

The key is to not deal with any pandas operation until you have loaded all the data. Only then you could use `DataFrame`'s [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records) or one of its other factory methods.

A nice SO question that has a little more discussion I found:
[Improve Row Append Performance On Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes)

## TL;DR

1. Measure the time to read all the files without dealing with pandas at all
2. If it proves to be much much faster ***and*** you have enough memory to load all the files' contents at once use another way to construct your `DataFrame`, say `DataFrame.from_records`