# Convert list to dataframe by adding list values to df within for loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple list

**Code to retrieve i, v list:**

```
 for i, v in enumerate(list_name_1):
    print(i, v)
```

**Output**

```
    5 -100
    4 30
    0 -90
    1 -80
    3 100
    2 1000
    and so on
```

I wish to store all these in a dataframe.

The problem is I am doing lot of calculations on list_name_1 within the for loop, hence I need to catch i and v values in the for loop only. So I cant do a simple `df=pd.DataFrame(list_name_1)` for e.g.

I will need to do something like below:

```
df = []
 for i, v in enumerate(list_name_1):
        print(i, v)
        some code to add i,v iteratively in columns i and v of df
```

Comment: You say "...of a dataframe with column names i and v", but in your example, all entries in the `list_name_1` are unique, so the DataFrame should have very many columns, and very few rows?

Comment: Hi In list we only have 2 types of values i and v. I want to convert these to a dataframe with 2 columns i and v. So df will have 2 columns and many rows

Comment: Bascially list is feature importance. i is feature number, v is feature's value.. So I want to get this data in a df and be able to do some operations on it in df format

Comment: I've added an answer that I think does what you want. Let me know if there are any unclarities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to create two lists, one which stores the calculated values of `i`, and one for `v`. So:

```
i_values = []
v_values = []
for i, v in enumerate(list_name_1):
    print(i, v)
    # Make calculations for i and v
    i_values.extend([calculated_i])
    v_values.extend([calculated_v])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"i": i_values, "v": v_values})
```

Comment: ```NameError: name 'calculated_i' is not defined``` error. I am getting this error

Comment: Works well, thanks. instead of calculated_i replaced with i

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to make calculations in the loop, that was why I called them `calculated_i`. But hey, if it works and you're satisfied its all good!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that:

```
for i, v in enumerate(list_name_1):
    diction = {'i': i, 'v': v}
    df = df.append(diction, ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know how you are doing the calculation, but I think it is a good way to catch all values.

Comment: If `list_name_1 ` is very long, the loop will become very slow and performance will deteriorate since `df.append()` is generally bad practice in loops. You can read more about why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use predifined syntax for this.Using for loops is really long way.

```
import pandas as pd

L = ["This","Is","A","List"]
M = ["This","Is","Also","List"]
#create new dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L,'col2':M})
print (df)


           col  col2
       0  This  This
       1    Is    Is
       2     A  Also
       3  List  List
```