# Plotly line plot from two dictionaries

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have two dictionaries:

```
days = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[3,4,5]}
vals = {'a':[10,20,30], 'b':[9,16,25]}
```

Using plotly (ideally plotly express) I would like one line plot with two lines: the first line being `days['a']` vs `vals['a']` and the second line being `days['b']` vs `vals['b']`. Of course in practice I may have many more potential lines. I am not sure how to pull this off. I'm happy to make a dataframe out of this data but not sure what the best structure is.

Thanks! Apologies for a noob question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# your data
days = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[3,4,5]}
vals = {'a':[10,20,30], 'b':[9,16,25]}

# generate a plot for each dictionary key
data = []
for k in days.keys():
    plot = go.Scatter(x=days[k],
                      y=vals[k],
                      mode="lines",
                      name=k # label for the plot legend
                     ) 
    data.append(plot)

# create a figure with all plots and display it
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

With Plotly Express:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

days = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5]}
vals = {'a': [10, 20, 30], 'b': [9, 16, 25]}

# build DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["days", "vals", "label"])
for k in days.keys():
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({
        "days": days[k],
        "vals": vals[k],
        "label": k
    }))

fig = px.line(df, x="days", y="vals", color="label")
fig.show()
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Oh interesting. I didn't know about plotly.graph_objects. Is it preferred to px?

Comment: Also, I am not sure this is quite what I wanted. This seems to be days['a'] vs vals['a'] and days['b'] vs vals['b']? Apologies if I misunderstand.

Comment: I misread your question. I will fix it in a second.

Comment: Thanks!!This is super useful.

Comment: Plotly express is very convenient if data comes from a DataFrame, but in this case using graph objects seemed simple enough.

Comment: Yeah. I am wondering if I should just build a dataframe out of it.

Comment: (very late but oh well) using df.append multiple times is not a good way to make dataframes, acc the documentation, append things to a list and make one dataframe out of that list. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes) for more!