# Converting large text/pgn files to JSON in Spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing

I need to convert PGN files to JSON so that I can then use Spark to convert them to Spark DataFrames and eventually create a Graph. I have wrote a python script to parse them as a DataFrame using Pandas but it is just too slow (around 56 minutes for 170k games (original guesstimate of 30 minutes but after profile I estimate 56 minutes)). I also tried using this repo: https://github.com/JonathanCauchi/PGN-to-JSON-Parser which gave me the JSON file but took 69 minutes for the 170k games.

I can change the PGN extension to a .txt and it seems to work the exact same so I assume there is more support for .txt to JSON but I am not sure.

I think Spark will be quicker than "normal" Python but I am lost how to do the conversion. Here is a sample below. There is 2billion games though so neither of my current approaches work as it'd take nearly 2 years if I were to use the PGN-to-JSON-Parser. Ideally a .txt to Spark DataFrames and ignoring the JSON altogether would be the ideal.

```
[Event "Rated Classical game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/j1dkb5dw"]
[White "BFG9k"]
[Black "mamalak"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2012.12.31"]
[UTCTime "23:01:03"]
[WhiteElo "1639"]
[BlackElo "1403"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+5"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-8"]
[ECO "C00"]
[Opening "French Defense: Normal Variation"]
[TimeControl "600+8"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 b6 3. a3 Bb7 4. Nc3 Nh6 5. Bxh6 gxh6 6. Be2 Qg5 7. Bg4 h5 8. Nf3 Qg6 9. Nh4 Qg5 10. Bxh5 Qxh4 11. Qf3 Kd8 12. Qxf7 Nc6 13. Qe8# 1-0
```

Edit: Added Profile for 20k games.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   26.828   26.828  395.848  395.848 /Users/danieljones/Documents – Daniel’s iMac/GitHub/ST446Project/ParsePGN.py:11(parse_pgn)
    20000    0.798    0.000  289.203    0.014 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:7614(append)
    20000    0.098    0.000  199.489    0.010 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:70(concat)
    20000    0.480    0.000  126.548    0.006 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:295(__init__)
   100002    0.212    0.000  122.178    0.001 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5199(_protect_consolidate)
    80002    0.076    0.000  122.177    0.002 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5210(_consolidate_inplace)
    40000    0.079    0.000  122.063    0.003 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5218(_consolidate)
    80002    0.170    0.000  121.830    0.002 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5213(f)
   100001    0.223    0.000   99.829    0.001 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:986(_consolidate_inplace)
    59999    0.451    0.000   96.718    0.002 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1898(_consolidate)
    80002    0.138    0.000   96.599    0.001 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:970(consolidate)
    79999   52.602    0.001   91.913    0.001 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1915(_merge_blocks)
    20000    7.432    0.000   79.741    0.004 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chess/pgn.py:1323(read_game)
    20000    0.361    0.000   72.843    0.004 /Users/danieljones/opt/anaconda3/envs/LSE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:456(get_result)
```

I'm not sure if "cumtime" is the best column to sort by but it seems that the append step takes a lot of the time up.

Here is my script:

```
def parse_pgn(pgn):
    games = []
    i = 0
    edges_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Event", "Round", "WhitePlayer", "BlackPlayer", "Result", "BlackElo",
                                     "Opening", "TimeControl", "Date", "Time", "WhiteElo"])

    while i < 20000:
        first_game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)

        if first_game is not None:
            Event = first_game.headers["Event"]
            Round = first_game.headers["Round"]
            White_player = first_game.headers["White"]
            Black_player = first_game.headers["Black"]
            Result = first_game.headers["Result"]  # Add condition to split this
            if Result == "1-0":
                Result = White_player
            elif Result == "0-0":
                Result = "Draw"
            else:
                Result = Black_player
            BlackELO = first_game.headers["BlackElo"]
            Opening = first_game.headers["Opening"]
            TimeControl = first_game.headers["TimeControl"]
            UTCDate = first_game.headers["UTCDate"]
            UTCTime = first_game.headers["UTCTime"]
            WhiteELO = first_game.headers["WhiteElo"]
            edges_df = edges_df.append({"Event": Event,
                                                "Round": Round,
                                                "WhitePlayer": White_player,
                                                "BlackPlayer": Black_player,
                                                "Result": Result,
                                                "BlackElo": BlackELO,
                                                "Opening": Opening,
                                                "TimeControl": TimeControl,
                                                "Date": UTCDate,
                                                "Time": UTCTime,
                                                "White": WhiteELO,
                                                }, ignore_index=True)
            games.append(first_game)
            i += 1
        else:
            pass

    return edges_df
```

Edit 2: Changed the append method to a dictionary. 20k now takes 78 seconds. Alot of the methods taking the time seem to come from the `chess` package, such as checking for legal moves, reading the board layout. None of this is important to my end goal so I am wondering if I can move away from using this package and split the file into seperate games myself, maybe at `[Event` as this is the start of each distinct game.

Comment: *have wrote a python script to parse them as a DataFrame using Pandas but it is just too slow (around 30 minutes for 170k games)* have you tried profiling or optimizing your code?

Comment: Great idea thanks. I have added this as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Do not `.append` to `pandas.DataFrame` in loop if you want to have short run time, you might read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes). You might first store your `dict`s in iterable and then create `pandas.DataFrame` from it. I would use `collections.deque` (from `collections` built-in module) for that as it is designed to sport high-speed `.append`, lets compare these different ways

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
def func1():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','z'])
    for i in range(1000):
        df = df.append({'x':i,'y':i*10,'z':i*100}, ignore_index=True)
    return df
def func2():
    store = collections.deque()
    for i in range(1000):
        store.append({'x':i,'y':i*10,'z':i*100})
    df = pd.DataFrame(store, columns=['x','y','z'])
    return df
```

These functions produce equal `pandas.DataFrame`s, I compared them using built-in module `timeit` following way

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('func1()',number=10,globals={'func1':func1}))
print(timeit.timeit('func2()',number=10,globals={'func2':func2}))
```

and got following outcome

```
18.370871236000312
0.02604325699940091
```

that is more than 500 times faster. Naturally *your mileage might vary*, but I suggest giving this optimization try.