# Pandas append is very slow, having problems using from_dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to append pandas dataframes. But I found out that append is very slow. This link [Improve Row Append Performance On Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50105723/15542251) suggests using from_dict instead of append. I tried to do the same but I am having a problem, converting a dataframe to_dict and back from dict to dataframe.

I have this dataframe df

```
        date   open   high    low  close  volume  average  barCount simb
0  3/31/2020  81.43  81.49  78.56  78.91  183417  80.0940     86742  xdt
1   4/1/2020  77.00  77.38  75.35  76.57   91420  76.4395     49399  xdt
2   4/2/2020  76.12  79.66  76.00  79.44   75298  78.4080     40614  xdt
3   4/3/2020  78.79  79.99  78.18  79.45   64965  79.0490     37140  xdt
4   4/6/2020  81.08  83.12  79.60  82.73   89395  81.3605     46247  xdt
5   4/7/2020  83.45  84.48  81.76  81.93   77722  83.3980     43947  xdt
6   4/8/2020  82.50  85.39  81.05  84.95   66202  83.4955     40256  xdt
7   4/9/2020  85.00  86.50  82.95  86.04   80298  85.1100     46184  xdt
8  4/13/2020  86.32  86.48  83.52  85.85   48114  85.1790     27280  xdt
9  4/14/2020  87.00  89.54  86.50  89.14   75528  88.4410     42810  xdt
```

I have several thousands of dataframes like this. I need to convert them to dict and then all of them to back to dataframe as it is shown on the link.

My code

```
d = {} 
i=0
d[i] =df.to_dict( 'index')
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, 'index')
```

I cannot get a proper dataframe with this code. I used different options instead of 'index' option, but it did not help. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the code

Comment: Use `pd.concat(df_list)`?

Comment: What's the reason for converting to a dictionary and then back to a dataframe? Seems inefficient.

Comment: @Vishnudev as far as I understand the performance of concat is also slow

Comment: @Nk03 yes, the column names are the same

Comment: `concat` would be the fastest compared to multiple dict operations. You could try benchmarking. Please don't put `concat` in a loop.

Comment: @fthomson i am happy with any other solution as long as it is not slow. My understanding is that from_dict is the fastest version

Comment: One more option that you can try -> `pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([i.values for i in df_list]), columns= df1.columns)`. NOTE:  I've not done performance comparison.

Comment: @Vishnudev could you give me an example. I am new to python, i can do concat but only in the loop

Comment: @BogdanTitomir my point is that you would most likely receive a large performance benefit from doing whatever you are trying to do inside the dataframe.

Comment: @BogdanTitomir no, it is only slow if you incrementally `pd.concat`. insteaad, *append all the intermediate df's into a single list*, and *then* use `pd.concat(df_list)`. there is probably no faster way than that

Comment: @BogdanTitomir your understanding about `from_dict` and `to_dict` is simply wrong. I don't know where you got it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i am pretty sure what i am doing is wrong. I am new to this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks i will try to work with pd.concat(df_list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read all the dataframes into a list

```
from glob import glob

dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob('*.csv')]
```

Then use `pd.concat`

```
big_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

NOTE: `glob('*.csv')` reads all `csv` files in the current working directory.

Comment: thanks, what if i do not read csv files. On every loop, i make some data manipulations and after that i get my desired dataframe. I need to read this dataframe to list, how can i do it.

Comment: How are your 1000 odd dataframes stored? In variables? @BogdanTitomir

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). @BogdanTitomir