# Optimising millions of Elasticsearch query export to csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I'm trying to export large set of `elasticsearch query` results to `csv` with `pandas`. I'm taking about minimum of `1 million` of `records` which needs to be `exported`. It is taking too much of time in execution, while checking the logs I see that `pandas` is taking too much of time while appending the data.

To achieve this I'm using `scan` helper function and split it into 5000 chunks, I'm able to extract all the `elasticsearch` data with infinite `scroll` with this

My code looks like:

```
for hit in scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query, scroll='20h', clear_scroll=True, size=5000):
    scan_source_data = hit["_source"]
    scan_id = hit["_id"]
    scan_doc_data = pandas.Series(scan_source_data, name=scan_id)
    scan_docs = scan_docs.append(scan_doc_data)

scan_docs.to_csv("/tmp/scandocs.csv", ",")
```

When I checked the logs:

```
[2021-08-26 08:10:51,876: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/server-logs/_search?scroll=20h&size=5000 [status:200 request:0.814s]
[2021-08-26 08:13:39,213: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_search/scroll [status:200 request:0.653s]
[2021-08-26 08:17:50,795: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_search/scroll [status:200 request:0.813s]
[2021-08-26 08:23:15,433: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_search/scroll [status:200 request:0.554s]
[2021-08-26 08:30:25,491: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_search/scroll [status:200 request:0.585s]
[2021-08-26 08:38:42,866: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] POST https://search-52bt6xrhhsi.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_search/scroll [status:200 request:0.483s]
```

As you can see first 5000 chunk took 3 minutes, next 5000 chunk took 4 minutes, next one 6 minutes, next 8 minutes and this time increases when the size of the `append` increases.

I tried exporting around `50,000` records in one go it took around `one and half hour` to get the `CSV`. While trying to export `200,000` records I get time gap of 1 hour between two `scroll` queries run in the logs and was running for more than 24 hours.

I'm a newbie to python world and doesn't know much about it, but I'm sure there must be some better way.

I'm unable to find an optimised way to resolve this. Any info on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit adding timing print statements to see if the `scan` call is slow, or the `for` loop is slow. If it is the `scan` then you might be out of luck.

```
import time

with open('/tmp/scandocs.csv','w') as f_out:
    scan_start_time = time.time()
    hits = scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query, scroll='20h', clear_scroll=True, size=5000)
    scan_duration = time.time()-scan_start_time
    print(scan_duration)

    loop_start_time = time.time()
    for hit in hits:
        scan_source_data = hit["_source"]
        scan_id = hit["_id"]
        output_line = '{},'.format(scan_id)
        output_line += ','.join(scan_source_data)
        f_out.write(output_line+'\n')

loop_duration = time.time()-loop_start_time
print(loop_duration)
```

Before edit:

Appending in pandas is slow ([Improve Row Append Performance On Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes)). Do you need to have all the `scan_doc_data` in memory at once? Or can you write it out as soon as you retrieve it? If you can write out immediately, I'd suggest writing directly to an open file handle and creating the CSV yourself line by line:

```
with open('/tmp/scandocs.csv','w') as f_out:
    for hit in scan(elastic_client, index=index, query=query, scroll='20h', clear_scroll=True, size=5000):
        scan_source_data = hit["_source"]
        scan_id = hit["_id"]
        output_line = '{},'.format(scan_id)
        output_line += ','.join(scan_source_data)
        f_out.write(output_line+'\n')
```

I haven't tested this so there may be errors

Comment: Hey Thanks @mitoRibo, Sorry for late response. I tried your code and it took same amount of time. I observed during this development, as the chunk size grows there is delay in execution. When I changed the chunk size to 500-1000 export were quiet fast. Got 2 million records exported in an hour with this. 

Upvote for your help

Comment: I'm guessing the `scan` function call is the source of slowness then. you could test this by adding some timing print statements like I've done in the edit above