# Nested dictionary to CSV convertion optimization

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dictionary, optimization

I have a dictionary like this:

```
no_empty_keys = {'783': [['4gsx', 'ADTQGS', 0.3333333333333333, {'A': ['A224', 'T226'], 'B': ['A224', 'T226']}, 504, 509], ['4gt0', 'ADTQGS', 0.3333333333333333, {'A': ['A224', 'T226'], 'B': ['A224', 'T226']}, 504, 509]],'1062': [['4gsx', 'AELTGY', 0.5, {'A': ['L175', 'T176', 'Y178'], 'B': ['L175', 'T176', 'Y178']}, 453, 458], ['4gt0', 'AELTGY', 0.5, {'A': ['L175', 'T176', 'Y178'], 'B': ['L175', 'T176', 'Y178']}, 453, 458]]}
```

My function to transform that into a CSV is this one:

```
epitope_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Epitope ID', 'PDB', 'Percent Identity', 'Epitope Mapped', 'Epitope Sequence', 'Starting Position', 'Ending Position'])
                for x in no_empty_keys:
                    for y in no_empty_keys[x]:
                        epitope_df = epitope_df.append({'Epitope ID': x, 'PDB': y[0], 'Percent Identity': y[2], 'Epitope Mapped' : y[3], 'Epitope Sequence' : y[1], 'Starting Position' : y[4], 'Ending Position' : y[5]}, ignore_index=True)
                epitope_df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

My output is a csv file like this:

[image]

It is working, but it isn't well optimized. The process is very slow when I run into a dictionary with more than > 10,000 entries. Any ideas on how to speed this process up? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with getting rid of `pandas.append`. Appending rows to DataFrames is [inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes). You can create a DataFrame in one go:

```
result = []
for x in no_empty_keys:
    for y in no_empty_keys[x]:
        result.append(
            {
                'Epitope ID': x,
                'PDB': y[0],
                'Percent Identity': y[2],
                'Epitope Mapped': y[3],
                'Epitope Sequence': y[1],
                'Starting Position': y[4],
                'Ending Position': y[5]
            }
        )

epitope_df = epitope_df.from_records(result)
epitope_df.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. You need to create the variable epitope_df first. But it is faster, indeed. Almost 10x faster (I checked using line profiler). I tried a different solution, using pd.concat, but yours is still faster (it is almost a tie). I will test it with a more extended dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write an ad hoc code by hand or use [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which generates such converters for you:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

no_empty_keys = {
    "783": [
        [ "4gsx", "ADTQGS", 0.3333333333333333, {"A": ["A224", "T226"], "B": ["A224", "T226"]}, 504, 509, ],
        [ "4gt0", "ADTQGS", 0.3333333333333333, {"A": ["A224", "T226"], "B": ["A224", "T226"]}, 504, 509, ],
    ],
    "1062": [
        [ "4gsx", "AELTGY", 0.5, {"A": ["L175", "T176", "Y178"], "B": ["L175", "T176", "Y178"]}, 453, 458,],
        [ "4gt0", "AELTGY", 0.5, {"A": ["L175", "T176", "Y178"], "B": ["L175", "T176", "Y178"]}, 453, 458, ],
    ],
}

columns = (
    "Epitope ID",
    "PDB",
    "Percent Identity",
    "Epitope Mapped",
    "Epitope Sequence",
    "Starting Position",
    "Ending Position",
)

# this is just a function, so it can be run on startup once and stored for
# further reuse
converter = (
    c.iter(
        c.zip(
            c.repeat(c.item(0)),
            c.item(1)
        ).iter(
            (c.item(0),) + tuple(c.item(1, i) for i in range(len(columns) - 1))
        )
    )
    .flatten()
    .gen_converter()
)

# here is the stuff to profile
Table.from_rows(
    converter(no_empty_keys.items()),
    header=columns,
).into_csv("out.csv")
```

Consider installing `black` and passing `debug=True` to `gen_converter` if you are curious on the code `convtools` generates under the hood.