# How to fill spaces in dates fast? Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have efficiency problem here, I have data like this:
[image: DataFrame]

I want to fill spaces of dates with that specific date, and `Quantity` 0 (for every `PrekesId`)
to look like this (screenshot only contains a part of data)
[image: DataFrame part-result]

I am using this code right now :

```
unique_products = data['PrekesId'].unique()
date_range = pd.date_range(start=data.Date.min(), end=data.Date.max(), freq='M')
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PrekesId', 'Year', 'Month', 'Quantity'])
for product in unique_products:
  for date in date_range:
    # if test[(test['Year'] == date.year) & (test['Month'] == date.month)]['Quantity'].empty:
    try:
      new_df = new_df.append({'PrekesId': product, 'Year': date.year, 'Month': date.month, 'Quantity': test[(test['Year'] == date.year) & (test['Month'] == date.month)]['Quantity'].iloc[0], 'Date': date}, ignore_index=True)
    except IndexError:
      new_df = new_df.append({'PrekesId': product, 'Year': date.year, 'Month': date.month, 'Quantity': 0, 'Date': date}, ignore_index=True)
new_df
```

It has taken 8 minutes for 15k row initial dataframe.

Edit:

My intention is to have a dataframe of size
`len(date_range) * len(unique_products)`
initial dataframe doesn't have rows where quantity is 0, and thus i have rows with skipping months.

Comment: Data as images is not helpful. Could you please paste it here?

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure how to paste a dataframe into here properly.

Comment: From the dataframes shown, it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. But I can tell that you are calling `.append` in a loop which usually causes performance problems. See here: [Improve Row Append Performance On Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27929472/3005167)

Comment: Could it also be that I'm using this lookup `test[(test['Year'] == date.year) & (test['Month'] == date.month)]['Quantity'].iloc[0]` basically 70k times?

Comment: @MB-F I've managed to make it 4x faster, down to 2 minutes, I guess it will work for now, thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.